# Django Query set with distinct and exclude together

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to send notification to users who has previously commented in the request. So, for this aim, I have to find distinct users and exclude current commenter(user) id from that list.

```
object_id_list = ScAns.objects.filter(username=username).values_list('id',flat=True)
```

result-> QuerySet [22]

```
actionUsers = ScAnsAction.objects.filter(req_id=request_id).values_list('user_id',flat=True).distinct().exclude(id__in=object_id_list)
```

result-> QuerySet [13, 15, 22]

final Result should not contain 22. It should give [13,15]

Comment: Have you tried doing the exclude before the distinct? (also you could avoid the `__in` by just doing `exclude(username=username)`..)

Comment: thanks, that helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the exclusion before calling distinct, also, to avoid the unnecessary `__in` you can just exclude based on the username.

```
actionUsers = ScAnsAction.objects.filter(req_id=request_id)).exclude(username=username).values_list('user_id',flat=True).distinct()
```